# How to take the value from the option field in datalist and add as a query to href? Trying to go href={/stock?id=}

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to take the value from the option field in datalist and add as a query to href? Trying to go href={/stock?id=}

```
<div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.searchContainer}>
                <form>
                    <input className={styles.input}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    value={searchTerm}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    list='tickers'
                     />  
                    <datalist id="tickers">
                        {searchResults.map(item => (
                            <option value={item}>{item}</option>
                            ))}
                        </datalist>
                        <button >Submit</button>
                </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you show your `handleChange` function ?

Comment: the handleChange function is just updating state ``` const handleChange = event => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
      };```

Comment: and where are you adding to `href`?

Comment: Inside your handleChange function, you can do event.target.value to get the selected option field value. And then if you're using react-router/hooks then in the history object you can update the search/hash value.

Comment: @Mohit Thank you that did the trick. Made an handleSubmit for the form and was able to update history

Comment: Cheers. Happy to help. Upvote it for others.

Comment: @Mohit I am not seeing upvote for comments. Could it be that new user arent allowed to upvote.

Comment: I guess so. No worries!!